# how to get datavaluefield from SelectList in mvc view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have bind data from selectlist in mvc controller

Here is my code

```
var getYear = db.yearMaster.OrderBy(y => y.Year).ToList();
SelectList yearList = new SelectList(getYear, "YearID", "Year");
ViewBag.YearListName = yearList;
```

Here is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FilterImage", "Glimpses", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("YearList", ViewBag.YearListName as SelectList, "Select Year")
}
```

Now, when I submit the data from the FormMethod.Post method at that time I want to pass the datavaluefield related to the selected item.

let for more clear,

there is 3 item in yearlist for ex:

```
value itemname
1     2011-2012
2     2012-2013
3     2013-2014
```

now when I select the 2011-2012 at that time I want that value i.e. 1. I want to store that value in `@Html.Hidden();`type.

Thank You.

Comment: You will get the options value attribute value as long as that SELECT is inside a form. Why do you want to store it in the hidden input ? It will be available in the `YearList` form item

Comment: if you have other idea then please share it. How can I select from yearlist form item

Comment: I still do not understand your problem. What are you trying to ? Where you want to get the selected option value ? If you use a parameter called YearList in your http post action method, you will get the selected option value when the form is submitted.

Comment: share how your http post action method looks like now

Comment: I have updated the question please review it.

Comment: You still did not answer my question. BTW, what you mean by " I want to store that value in @Html.Hidden();type." ????

Comment: I want to store selected item value inside the @html.hidden()

Comment: What you mean `@html.hidden()`. `@html.hidden()` is a helper method. You call the method. You cannot store stuff inside a method!

Comment: Also your question has unclear information. You want to get the selected data in http post action method when user submits the form or when user selects an item from the form (what you want to happen when user selects an item) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will render a SELECT element with `name` attribute value set to `YearList`. That means when you **submit the form**, the selected option value will be available for the form item key `YearList`. So if you use a parameter with the same name in your action method, you will get that value.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FilterImage(int yearList)
{
    // You have the value in yearList param now
    // to do  : return something
}
```

> now when I select the 2011-2012 at that time I want that value i.e. 1.
>   I want to store that value in @Html.Hidden();type

This does not make any sense. `@Html.Hidden()` is a helper method to render a hidden input element. You call a method to get something, you cannot store some value to a method!

If you are trying to set the selected value of the dropdown to a hidden element, you should use the javascript to do that. Here is an example using jQuery `val()` method.

```
$(function(){

   $("#YearList").change(function(){

       $("#yearID").val($(this).val());
       alert("The value of yearID input is "+  $("#yearID").val());
   }); 

});
```

This code will set the selected option value to an input element with Id `yearID` in your page.